# Permission denied for gitconfig in Microsoft hosted devops agent

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

Using git command in pipeline :
git config --system --add 'url azure-devops' Authorization:Bearer $token

output:
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/f76ec2f0-0843-41ba-8959-8534015c5e43.sh
error: could not lock config file /etc/gitconfig: **Permission denied**
##[error]Bash exited with code '255'.
Finishing: Configure Git token

I tried to set permission as well but it doesnot work. Also its related to etc directory which need root user. Any idea  or suggestions on this, please?

Comment: Don't try setting it for the system. Your pipeline does not have permissions for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noted, your command requires root and it's failing because you don't have it.  That's because you've used the `--system` flag to `git config`, which modifies the system configuration file, usually stored in `/etc/gitconfig`.

It would be better to use `--global` if you need something for all repositories on a CI system, and that file should be modifiable by your user.  Alternately, if you have just a single repository already and want to use it, you can use `--local` (or omit the flag) to set it only locally.